# Issue with decrypting aes password in php

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I am working on some PHP code to perform AES string encryption and decryption. The encryption is working fine but I can't seem to decrypt it.

Below is the code that does the encryption and adds the required padding.

```
function encrypt($data) 
    { 
        $iv = "PRIVATE";
        $key = CIPHERKEY;

        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, addpadding($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    }

    function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 16)
    {
        $len = strlen($string);
        $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
        $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

        return $string;
    }
```

The code above is working fine the code below where it does the decryption keeps on failing. I try and do the decryption and then strip the padding but false is always returned from the padding function.

Below is the code that does the decryption and the stripping.

```
function strippadding($string)
{
    $slast = ord(substr($string, -1));
    $slastc = chr($slast);
    $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
    if(preg_match("/$slastc{".$slast."}/", $string)){
        $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-$slast);
        return $string;
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}

    function decrypt($data)
    {
        $iv = "PRIVATE";
        $key = CIPHERKEY;

        //$decoded = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $decrytped = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $base64Decoded = base64_decode($decrytped);
        return strippadding($base64Decoded);
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your decryption method, the decrypt and base64 steps are backwards. It's important that in whatever order you do your operations for encrypting, you do the reverse to decrypt.

In your encrypt method, you're base64 encoding the ciphertext:

```
base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, addpadding($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
```

When you decrypt, you need to undo the base64 encoding, and then decrypt that result.

```
$base64Decoded = base64_decode($data);
$decrytped = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $base64Decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Also, it looks like mcrypt will handle padding uneven blocks, so your addpadding() method might be superfluous.

Comment: PHP mcrypt's padding mechanism (null bytes) is different than what most other crypto libraries use (PKCS#7)

Comment: @Yuliy good point on the padding. I did a quick cursory look and it seemed like it did padding, but I didn't investigate which modes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a too-short IV which is less than the blocksize. I assume this results in using a different IV on decryption.  Blocksize is 16 bytes, so the IV should be 16 bytes, but your fixed-string IV is only 7 bytes (8 if you count the terminating zero byte which the underlying C code probably adds).

Instead of using a fixed string, you should be using a random IV generated by [`mcrypt_create_iv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php).  You can find out the length of one block by using `mcrypt_get_iv_size()` as shown in Example 1 in the `mcrypt_create_iv()` PHP manual.  You would then send/store the random IV prepended to the ciphertext so you know what the IV was on decryption.

Also, mcrypt does its own padding, so you don't need to. And, as mfanto pointed out, you need to decode Base64 before decryption, not after.

Comment: the IV PRIVATE isn't the actual IV, I'm using, I didn't want to post this online

Comment: The IV should be random and change for every message, and isn't required to be kept confidential. Usually it's included with the message.

Comment: @Boardy Okay; my advice in the second paragraph still applies: you should be using random, unpredictable IVs per message.

Comment: @Boardy yeah the IV does not need to be protected.

Comment: If the IV is random wouldn't that mean each time the encryption is done a different string would be created. If that is the case how would you encrypt a password and then ensure that the user entered the correct password.

Comment: You need to save the IV along with the encrypted message. The purpose of an IV is so that identical messages with identical keys produce different encryptions. If this is for a password though, you don't want to encrypt. Passwords shouldn't be reversible, you should hash them.

Comment: Use these easy functions for password hashing: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat - they will be in PHP starting with version 5.5 natively.